# Extract two values from files

Tags: scripting

I would like to extract two values from a series of .txt files.

This is the last two lines (line 49 & line 50) of my .txt file

```
1  13593 3434 2.2585  0.9
2   3333  333 3.7118  0.8
```

& I want to extract the 4th column (ex. 2.2585 & 3.7118) of line 49 and line 50 from each .txt file.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks so much

Comment: Are the values always in 4th column? And you want the 4th column value of only 49th and 50th lines of each .txt file or all values at 4th column of  each .txt files?

Comment: Please edit and clarify your question; do you always want to extract the values from the last two lines of each file?

Comment: Yes, the values are always in the 4th column, and I want the 4th column of only 49th and 50th line of each text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` for text processing. The following awk statement reads the file 'input' and prints the value at column 4 of line 49 and 50.

> awk 'FNR==49 || FNR==50 {print $4}' input

Now to read all the files in the directory (assuming all files are in same directory) you can run a for loop to read filenames. So the final statement will be like -

> for file in *; do awk 'FNR==49 || FNR==50 {print $4}' "$file"; done

And as  **trosos** mentioned, the inputs files are only `.txt` format. So we can do

> awk 'FNR==49 || FNR==50 {print $4}' *.txt

Comment: You can avoid the `for` and just do `awk 'FNR>48{print $4}' *.txt`

Comment: Oh! yes. She has specified ".txt" format of the files. Thanks, I am modifying my answer.

Comment: Thanks trishnendu, maulinglawns & trosos. It worked nicely !